# mapquest direct tile access alternates /Fix?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, mapquest

Mapquest has stopped direct tile access on 11/07/2016.

[Error Page - Screenshot. Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBu33.png)  
I have the following function. Can someone suggest whats the quick fix if any,  to sort this out . 
This is the copy of code

```
 <esi:remove>
<div class="child" style="float:left;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/ZeroClipboard.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ZeroClipboard.setDefaults( { moviePath: '<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("js/ZeroClipboard.swf"); ?>' } );
</script>
<?php
    $clipboardicon = $this->getSkinUrl('images/clipboard.png');
    //Load required php libs
    require_once('lib/Map/longilat.php');
    require_once('lib/Map/markermaker.php');
    require_once('lib/Map/popup.php');

    $orders = Mage::registry('mapOrders');
    $unsetorders = Mage::registry('mapUnbooked');
    $undeliveredorders = Mage::registry('mapUndelivered');
    $searchedorder = Mage::registry('searchedOrder');

    //Get home depo pin data
    $ll = postCode2Geog('wv1');
    $long = $ll[0];
    $lat =  $ll[1];
    $baseurl = stristr(Mage::getBaseUrl(), "index", TRUE);

    $orderStock = Mage::registry('mapStock');

    if($_GET['postcode'])
    {
        $getPostcode = $_GET['postcode'];
        $postcodeToMark = $_GET['postcode'];
    }
    ?>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * OpenLayers Map Variables Setup
     */
    var map;
    var arrayOSM;
    var arrayAerial;
    var baseOSM;
    var baseAerial;
    var longHome = "<?php echo $long ?>";
    var latiHome = "<?php echo $lat ?>";
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var iconHome = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/home-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconBlueStar = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/bluestar-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconStar = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/star-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconLSW = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/lsw-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconPallet = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/pallet-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconInterlink = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/interlink-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconEbay = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/ebay-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconGreen = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/marker-green.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconRed = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var iconMagnifier = new OpenLayers.Icon("<?php echo $baseurl.'js/openlayers/img/magnifier-marker.png';?>", size, offset);
    var home = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Home" );
    var postcodemarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Entered Postcode" );
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Unknown Markers" );
    var lswmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "LSW Deliveries" );
    var palletmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Pallet Deliveries" );
    var ebaymarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Ebay Deliveries" );
    var interlinkmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Interlink Deliveries" );

    var unsetmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Unreserved Without Delivery Dates" );
    var undeliveredmarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Unreserved With Delivery Dates" );
    unsetmarkers.setVisibility(false);
    undeliveredmarkers.setVisibility(false);

    var searchedorder = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Entered Order Number" );

    var unsetmarkersgreen = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Reserved Without Delivery Dates" );
    var undeliveredmarkersgreen = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Reserved With Delivery Dates" );
    /**
     * End OpenLayers Map Variables Setup
     */

    /**
     * OpenLayers Pin Functions
     */
    var markerHover = function(evt)
    {
        if (this.popup == null)
        {
            this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
            map.addPopup(this.popup);
            this.popup.show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.popup.toggle();
        }
        OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
    };

    var markerClick = function(evt)
    {
        <?php
            // $baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl()."/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/"; // Bad Url: directly references "admin" as opposed to getting url with adminhtml
            $baseurl = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view"); //"adminhtml/" gets automagically turned into the admin url
            $url = stristr($baseurl, "/key/");
            $baseurl = str_replace($url, "/order_id/", $baseurl);
        ?>
        //window.location = '<?php echo $baseurl ?>'+this.id+'<?php echo $url ?>';
        if(this.id != null)
        {
            window.open('<?php echo $baseurl ?>'+this.id+'<?php echo $url ?>');
        }
        // window.alert(this.id);
    }
    /**
     * End OpenLayers Pin Functions
     */

    // Function for setting pin data and location
    function setMarker(lon, lat, pcode, orderno, layerI, iconI, id, productText, name)
    {
        var lonLatMarker = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(layerI, lonLatMarker);
        feature.id = id;
        feature.closeBox = true;
        feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble, {autoSize:true } );
        if(orderno)
        {
            ordertext = '<b>OrderNo:</b> '+orderno;
        }
        else
        {
            ordertext = '';
        }
        feature.data.popupContentHTML = '<div id="idInfo"><p><b>Name:</b> '+name+'</p><p><b>PostCode:</b> '+pcode+ordertext+'</p></div><div id="prodInfo">'+productText+'</div>';
        feature.data.overflow = "hidden";

        var icon = iconI.clone();
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLatMarker, icon);
        marker.feature = feature;

        marker.events.register("mouseover", feature, markerHover);
        marker.events.register("mouseout", feature, markerHover);
        marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);

        layerI.addMarker(marker);
    }

    // Initialize OpenLayers Map
    function init()
    {
        // Map Setup
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        arrayOSM = ["http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg"];

        baseOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MapQuest-OSM Tiles", arrayOSM);

        //Add Map Layers
        map.addLayer(home);
        // map.addLayer(markers); //Test layer
        map.addLayer(postcodemarkers);
        map.addLayer(lswmarkers);
        map.addLayer(palletmarkers);
        map.addLayer(ebaymarkers);
        map.addLayer(interlinkmarkers);
        map.addLayer(markers);
        <?php
        //Add Layer For Orders Without Delivery Dates
        if($unsetorders)
        {
            ?>
            map.addLayer(unsetmarkers);
            map.addLayer(unsetmarkersgreen);

            <?php
        }

        //Add Layer For Orders With Delivery Dates
        if($undeliveredorders)
        {
            ?>
            map.addLayer(undeliveredmarkers);
            map.addLayer(undeliveredmarkersgreen);
            <?php
        }

        //add layer for searched order
        if($searchedorder != null)
        {
            ?>
            map.addLayer(searchedorder);
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        //Add Map View
        map.addLayer(baseOSM)

        //Create Home Pin
        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(longHome,latiHome).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject()),iconHome);
        marker.id = "LSW Warehouse";
        marker.events.register("mousedown", marker, function() {alert(this.id);});
        home.addMarker(marker);

        //Add Map Controls
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

        <?php
        $postcodes_notfound = array();
        //Create Pins For Orders Matching Date Requirement
        foreach ($orders as $order)
        {
            $additional = "";
            if($order['organization'] != null || $order['organization'] != "")
            {
                $temp = explode('|', $order['organization']);
                $oddeven = "org-odd";
                foreach ($temp as $value)
                {
                    $org = explode('@',$value);
                    $additional .= "<div class='org-block ".$oddeven."''><div class='org-recipient'>From: ".$org[6]." -> To: ".$org[7]."</div><div><b>".$org[1]."</b></div><div>".str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $org[2])."</div><div class='org-deadline'>Deadline: ".$org[3]."</div></div>";
                    if($oddeven == "org-odd")
                    {
                        $oddeven = "org-even";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $oddeven = "org-odd";
                    }
                }
            }
            $line = postCode2Feature($order['postcode'],$order['shipping_description'],$order['increment_id'],$order['parent_id'],$order,$additional,$order['city']);
            echo $line."\r\n";
            if($line == null)
            {
                $postcodes_notfound[] = "Order Id: ".$order['increment_id']." | Postcode: ".$order['postcode']."<img class='clipboard' src='".$clipboardicon."' data-clipboard-text='".$order['postcode']."' />";
            }
        }

        //Create Pins For Orders Without Delivery Dates
        if($unsetorders)
        {
            $csv = "Unbooked\r\nOrder No,Status,Order Date\r\n";
            foreach ($unsetorders as $unsetorder)
            {
                $additional = "";
                if($order['organization'] != null || $order['organization'] != "")
                {
                    $temp = explode('|', $unsetorder['organization']);
                    $oddeven = "org-odd";
                    foreach ($temp as $value)
                    {
                        $org = explode('@',$value);
                        $additional .= "<div class='org-block ".$oddeven."''><div class='org-recipient'>From: ".$org[6]." -> To: ".$org[7]."</div><div><b>".$org[1]."</b></div><div>".str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $org[2])."</div><div class='org-deadline'>Deadline: ".$org[3]."</div></div>";
                        if($oddeven == "org-odd")
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-even";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-odd";
                        }
                    }
                }
                $line = postCode2Feature($unsetorder['postcode'],"unset",$unsetorder['increment_id'],$unsetorder['parent_id'],$unsetorder,$additional,$unsetorder['city']);
                echo $line."\r\n";
                if($line == null)
                {
                    $csv .= $unsetorder['increment_id'].",".$unsetorder['status'].",".$unsetorder['psop_delivery_date']."," . $unsetorder['postcode'] ."Not Found\r\n";
                    $postcodes_notfound[] = "Order Id: ".$unsetorder['increment_id']." | Postcode: ".$unsetorder['postcode']."<img class='clipboard' src='".$clipboardicon."' data-clipboard-text='".$order['postcode']."' />";
                }
                else
                {
                    $csv .= $unsetorder['increment_id'].",".$unsetorder['status'].",".$unsetorder['psop_delivery_date']."\r\n";
                }
                $csv .= $unsetorder['increment_id'].",".$unsetorder['status'].",".$unsetorder['psop_delivery_date']."\r\n";
                $unbookedcounter++;
            }
        }

        //Create Pins For Orders With Delivery Dates
        if($undeliveredorders)
        {
            $csv .= "Undelivered\r\nOrder No,Status,Order Date\r\n";
            foreach ($undeliveredorders as $undeliveredorder)
            {
                $additional = "";
                if($order['organization'] != null || $order['organization'] != "")
                {
                    $temp = explode('|', $undeliveredorder['organization']);
                    $oddeven = "org-odd";
                    foreach ($temp as $value)
                    {
                        $org = explode('@',$value);
                        $additional .= "<div class='org-block ".$oddeven."''><div class='org-recipient'>From: ".$org[6]." -> To: ".$org[7]."</div><div><b>".$org[1]."</b></div><div>".str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $org[2])."</div><div class='org-deadline'>Deadline: ".$org[3]."</div></div>";
                        if($oddeven == "org-odd")
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-even";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-odd";
                        }
                    }
                }
                $line = postCode2Feature($undeliveredorder['postcode'],"undelivered",$undeliveredorder['increment_id'],$undeliveredorder['parent_id'],$undeliveredorder,$additional,$undeliveredorder['city']);
                echo $line."\r\n";
                if($line == null)
                {
                    $csv .= $undeliveredorder['increment_id'].",".$undeliveredorder['status'].",".$undeliveredorder['psop_delivery_date']."," . $undeliveredorder['postcode'] ." Not Found\r\n";
                    $postcodes_notfound[] = "Order Id: ".$undeliveredorder['increment_id']." | Postcode: ".$undeliveredorder['postcode']."<img class='clipboard' src='".$clipboardicon."' data-clipboard-text='".$order['postcode']."' />";
                }
                else
                {
                    $csv .= $undeliveredorder['increment_id'].",".$undeliveredorder['status'].",".$undeliveredorder['psop_delivery_date']."\r\n";
                }
                $undeliveredcounter++;
            }
        }

        //Create Pins For Entered Postcode
        if($postcodeToMark)
        {
            echo postCode2FeatureCustom($postcodeToMark,'postcodemarkers','iconBlueStar','Marked Postcode');
        }

        //Create Pins For Searched Order
        if($searchedorder)
        {
            $orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($searchedorder['parent_id']);
            $inStock = $orderStock[$searchedorder['parent_id']]['stocked'];

            if($inStock)
            {
                $stockStatus = "<div class='stock_status'><b>Stock: </b><div style='background-color: green; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;'></div></div>";
            }
            else
            {
                $stockStatus = "<div class='stock_status'><b>Stock: </b><div style='background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;'></div></div> ";
            }

            if($searchedorder['psop_delivery_date'])
            {
                $planning = '<p><b>Planning Date: ' . $searchedorder['psop_delivery_date'] .'</b></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                $planning = "";
            }

            $additional = products2Html($orderObj->getAllItems()) . $stockStatus . $planning;

            echo postCode2FeatureCustom($searchedorder['postcode'],'searchedorder','iconMagnifier',$searchedorder['customer_name'],$searchedorder['parent_id'],$searchedorder['increment_id'],$additional,$searchedorder['city']);
        }
        ?>

        //Center Map View To Warhouse Pin
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(longHome,latiHome).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject()), 7);
    }
    init();
</script>
</div>

<?php //Debug For Unbooked and Undelivered Orders ?>
<div>
    <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/exportmap'); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="csv" name="csv" value="<?php echo $csv; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
echo "<br>Unbooked Counter: ".$unbookedcounter."<br>";
echo "Undelivered Counter: ".$undeliveredcounter."<br>";
echo "<br><b>Postcodes Not Found</b><br>";
foreach ($postcodes_notfound as $line)
{
    echo $line."<br>";
}
 ?>
<br>
<div><b>This Dates Orders</b></div>

<ul id="orderList" class="mapOrderList">
    <?php
    $oddeven = "odd";
    foreach ($orders as $order)
    {
            $baseurl = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view"); //"adminhtml/" gets automagically turned into the admin url
            $url = stristr($baseurl, "/key/");
            $baseurl = str_replace($url, "/order_id/", $baseurl);
            $link = $baseurl . $order['parent_id'] . $url;
        ?>
        <li class="mapOrder <?php echo $oddeven ?>">
            <div class="orderId"><?php echo "<a href='".$link."' target='_blank'>".$order['increment_id']."</a>" ?></div>
            <div class="customerName"><?php echo $order['customer_name'] ?></div>
            <?php
            if($order['organization'] != null || $order['organization'] != "")
            {
            ?>
            <div class="bulb">
                <div class="popup">
                    <?php
                    $temp = explode('|', $order['organization']);
                    $oddeven = "org-odd";
                    foreach ($temp as $value)
                    {
                        $org = explode('@',$value);
                        echo "<div class='org-block ".$oddeven."''><div class='org-recipient'>From: ".$org[6]." -> To: ".$org[7]."</div><div><b>".$org[1]."</b></div><div>".str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br>", $org[2])."</div><div class='org-deadline'>Deadline: ".$org[3]."</div></div>";
                        if($oddeven == "org-odd")
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-even";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $oddeven = "org-odd";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="products">
                <?php
                $products = $orderStock[$order['parent_id']]['products'];
                foreach ($products as $key => $productTemp)
                {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($key);
                    echo "<div class='productSku'>".$product['sku']."</div><div class='productInfo'>Qty: ".$productTemp['ordered_qty']."</div>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
        if($oddeven == "odd")
        {
            $oddeven = "even";
        }
        else
        {
            $oddeven = "odd";
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
for(i in elems)
{
    if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' clipboard ') > -1)
    {
        var target = elems[i];
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard(target);
    }
}
</script>
</esi:remove>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OSM:

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
```

MapQuest won't be available, except from MapQuest APIs. Also, according to their new TOS, no caching or storing is allowed. See [here](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/there-still-way-access-mapquest-open-data) for more details.

EDIT: update the beginning of your init method by:

```
function init()
{
    // Map Setup
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    // Create a layer with OSM map:
    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    //Add Map Layers
    map.addLayer(home);
    // map.addLayer(markers); //Test layer
    map.addLayer(postcodemarkers);
    map.addLayer(lswmarkers);
    map.addLayer(palletmarkers);
    map.addLayer(ebaymarkers);
    map.addLayer(interlinkmarkers);
    map.addLayer(markers);
    <?php
    //Add Layer For Orders Without Delivery Dates
    if($unsetorders)
    {
        ?>
        map.addLayer(unsetmarkers);
        map.addLayer(unsetmarkersgreen);

        <?php
    }

    //Add Layer For Orders With Delivery Dates
    if($undeliveredorders)
    {
        ?>
        map.addLayer(undeliveredmarkers);
        map.addLayer(undeliveredmarkersgreen);
        <?php
    }

    //add layer for searched order
    if($searchedorder != null)
    {
        ?>
        map.addLayer(searchedorder);
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    //Add the OSM layer:
    map.addLayer(osmLayer)
```

Comment: I can't find how to use that fix ? I am designer,  absolutely New to Mapquest. Just covering this for developer who on holidays. I have updated the code, would be grateful if you can suggest anything .